# refresh modal window without closing it

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have image thumbnails in 100s of directories.  I am using PHP to retrieve the images.  A bootstrap modal with id `#imagePalette` window pops up on clicking a button and displays all the images in the directory.

**In javascript**

```
$.post('getCroppedImages.php',{'location': location, 'brand':brand},function(data) {
var imagemodal = $('#imagePalette');
imagemodal.find('.modal-title').html('Brand: ' + brand + ' in ' + location);
imagemodal.find('.modal-body').html(data).show();
});
```

PHP code that retrieves the images:

```
$path = "projects/" . $database . '/' . $match . '/' . $location . '/' . $brandname . '/*.jpg';
$files = glob($path);
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    $filname = basename($num, ".jpg");
    $imgname = basename($num);
    $img = $path . $imgname;
    $filnam = substr($filname, -9,9);
    $filnam = rtrim($filnam);
    echo '<ul class="croppeditem" id="croppeditem">';
    echo '<li style="list-style:none;cursor:pointer" ><img onclick="clickCroppedImage(this.id); return false"; src="'.$num.'" id="'.$filnam.'"/>';
    echo '<figcaption class="caption" name="caption">' . $filnam . '</figcaption>';
    echo '</li></ul>';

}
```

The above code works perfectly.  It displays the images.  I have a function `clickCroppedImage` attached to each image.  When the user clicks on a image in the modal window, this function triggers another php that `deletes` the image from the folder.

This deletion also works without any trouble.  I am trying to refresh the modal modal without closing it so that the current set of images in the folder gets displayed. I have written similar php and javascript code and used `unlink` to delete the image from the folder.

**In Javascript**

```
$.post('deleteAnnCroppedImage.php', {'folder':wd, 'matchLst':matchLst, "imgPath" : clickedImg, 'currentAnnotCheckLocation': currentAnnotCheckLocation, 'currentAnnotCheckBrand': currentAnnotCheckBrand}, function(data){
          //imagemodal.find('.modal-body').html().show();
          var imagemodal = $('#imagePalette');
          imagemodal.find('.modal-body').html("");
          imagemodal.find('.modal-body').html(data).show();

        });
```

PHP Code

```
$currentAnnotPath = "projects/" . $database . '/' . $match . '/' . $location . '/' . $brandname . '/*.jpg';
$files = glob($currentAnnotPath);
$imgPath = $_POST['imgPath'];
unlink($imgPath);
//echo "Deleted Image";

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    $filname = basename($num, ".jpg");
    $imgname = basename($num);
    $img = $currentAnnotPath . $imgname;
    $filnam = substr($filname, -9,9);
    $filnam = rtrim($filnam);
    echo '<ul class="croppeditem" id="croppeditem">';
    echo '<li style="list-style:none;cursor:pointer" ><img onclick="clickCroppedImage(this.id); return false"; src="'.$num.'" id="'.$filnam.'"/>';
    echo '<figcaption class="caption" name="caption">' . $filnam . '</figcaption>';
    echo '</li></ul>';    
}
```

The php scripts returns the ul li data correctly which I can print to console.  However, I am not able to refresh the modal body and display the returned images.  I tried different combinations, but the modal window does not show any reaction.

How do I clear the modal body and reload the images without closing the modal window?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use AJAX if I understood your problem correctly.
After a user deleted an image you have to trigger a AJAX request and change the content of the modal.

A good introduction to AJAX can be found via google.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reach the modal-body element. 
First of all make sure you can see it from the current function scope.

Sample codes that are working with the basic bootstrap modal:

Pure JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML = '<p>some html</p>';
```

jQuery:

```
$('#imagePalette .modal-body:first').html('<p>some html</p>');
```

If there is an iFrame and the modal is inside than you should get into the iFrame document first from JavaScript.

*Other:
In these cases you can use jQuery wrapper instead of introducing a new variable. You won't loose performance but it will make this code more readable.*

Comment: Thank you....I found a solution which is as follows: `var imagemodal = $('#imagePalette');
          $("#imagePalette .modal-body").html('');
          $("#imagePalette .modal-body").html(data).show();`  ....  This sets the `modal-body` in the second line and reloads the `'modal-body` in the third line.